# Python и Entry. Как обработать клик

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

(Python 3.8, tkinter)
Здравствуйте, как обработать нажатие на поле вводе Entry?
Хочу сделать "Маску ввода" для поля "Дата" (Например, до нажатие на поле ввода, поле занято символами "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ", после нажатия - оно очищается).
Если есть более простой вариант, буду благодарен за информацию о нём.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Сам же нашёл ответ на свой вопрос, немного разобравшись с темой.
(Entry поле//любое другое).bind(Какая кнопка нажата, Функция)
В самой функции есть проверка, заполнено ли поле ввода символами "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ", либо же оно пусто.